# Simple number games in R Studio for beginners

Tags: r

I am trying to write a simple number game in R studio. I pick a random number and see if it matches the user's number input. If it does, "Bingo" will appear and if it does not, "Higher", "Lower" or "You are so close" appears.

However, I keep getting the error message:

> Error: unexpected '}' in "  }" and Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion

```
nonnegative <- function (x) {
  if (x < 0) {
    print (x*-1)
  } else {
    print (x)
  }
}

guessnumber <- function (guess, Rs_number) {
  if (nonnegative (guess - Rs_number) < 10) {
    print ("You are so close")
  } else (guess == Rs_number) {
    print ('Bingo"')
  } else (guess > Rs_number) {
    print("Lower")
  } else {
    print ("Higher")
  } 

}

guess <- as.numeric(readline(prompt="Guess: "))
Rs_number <- sample(1:100, 1)
guessnumber <- function (guess, Rs_number)
```

Comment: Passing comment: sample ( 1:100, 1 ) is a nice trick that I haven't seen before. I will definitely be using it in future -- thanks!

Comment: @plucky_underdog: You can even do `sample(100, 1)`, which is equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

There are few mistakes in the code.

1) In `nonnegative` function you should `return` the number and not `print` it

2) you should use `else if` to test another condition and not only `else`

Here is one way to write the function

```
guessnumber <- function (guess) {
    Rs_number <- sample(1:100, 1)
    print(Rs_number)
    if (guess == Rs_number) 
       print('Bingo')
    else if (abs(guess - Rs_number) < 10) 
       print ('You are so close')
    else if (guess > Rs_number) 
       print("Lower")
    else print("Higher")
}

guessnumber(28)
#[1] 61
#[1] "Higher"

guessnumber(28)
#[1] 24
#[1] "You are so close"
```

Answer (score 1):

Ronak makes some good suggestions for how to make your code work, but I cant't help noticing that there is an inherent flaw in the design, in that you can only make one guess for each number. Just for a bit of fun I had a go at making a version of this game where you can make multiple guesses. It's not quite beginner friendly, but I think it could be a nice challenge for a student that have a solid grip on R fundamentals like functions and conditionals. The two key concepts introduced here is to prompt for user interaction, represented by `readline()`, and recursion, represented by `Recall()`.

```
p <- function(num) {
    guess <- type.convert(readline())
    if (guess == num) {
        return(cat("\nGood job, that's correct!"))
    }
    d <- guess - num
    if (d < 0) {
        msg <- "\nHigher"
    } else {
        msg <- "\nLower"
    }
    if (abs(d) < 10) {
        msg <- paste0(msg, ", but it's close")
    }
    cat(msg, ". Please try again.\n\n", sep="")
    Recall(num)
}


numbergame <- function(numr=1:25) {
    num <- sample(numr, 1)
    prompt <- paste0(
      "Can you guess what number I'm thinking of? ",
      "It's a number between ", min(numr), " and ", max(numr)
    )
    cat(prompt, ".\n\n", sep="")
    p(num)
}
```

---

```
set.seed(1)
numbergame()

# Can you guess what number I'm thinking of? It's a number between 1 and 25.
# 
# 17
# 
# Lower. Please try again.
# 
# 8
# 
# Lower, but it's close. Please try again.
# 
# 4
# 
# Higher, but it's close. Please try again.
# 
# 6
# 
# Higher, but it's close. Please try again.
# 
# 7
# 
# Good job, that's correct!
#
```